# Generate image preview of 3d mesh using command line

Tags: gratis, image-processing, 3d, image-conversion

Is there any tool to generate image previews of a 3d model? Currently using OBJ format.

The goal is to do a bulk generation to quickly detect which are the characteristics of each OBJ.

So far I've been using **Meshlab** to do it manually. I found there is a **meshlabserver**, but I'm not sure if it's capable of generating the previews.

Preferably it should be for Linux, not a limitation though. Definitely something unpaid. For the preview format, I would prefer a raster (png, bmp, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PyVista](https://www.pyvista.org/) (a Python vtk wrapper with sugar syntax) seems to be the best option so far.

It reads several formats (stl, obj, vtk, etc).

There are examples of generating [mp4](https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/02-plot/movie.html) and even [gif](https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/02-plot/gif.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try gnuplot.  Part of the GNU software universe (linux, *bsd) but there are ports for most to windows/mac.

It's been years.  You may need to transform your data file.